# Qué código podría servirme para activar/desactivar un botón cada cierto tiempo por cada vez que le de un click?

Tags: java, android

Si me pudieran dar una idea del código o que función de Android Studio podría servirme para eso sería genial, desde ya, muchas gracias (pregunto por acá porque no encuentro nada en la web y menos en youtube).

Lo que quiero es que cuando le de click al botón se active el TimerTask y mientras el TimerTask este activo no se le pueda dar más clicks al botón (que el botón esté desactivado) hasta que se termine el conteo del TimerTask.

Ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listaFallos.size(); i++) {
                if (listaFallos.get(i).equals("1")) {
                    playAudios.playAudio(listaAudios.get(i));
                }
  }

  //al finalizar el bucle creas TimerTask

     timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         //Realiza tarea!...
        }
    };
    // Aquí se pone en marcha el timer CADA 2 MINUTOs
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, TIEMPOESPERA);
```

Comment: Recuerda que es recomendable agregar lo que has investigado o tratado. Obten reputación para realizar este tipo de preguntas en el [chat].

Comment: Te recomiendo poner alguna imagen que sirva de guía, ya sea algo que hagas o sea algo que viste.

Answer (score 1):

Para desactivar tu botón.

```
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         boton.setEnable(false) // con esto no podroas pulsarlo hasta que lo actives
        }
```

Y luego cuando quieras activarlo : `boton.setEnable(true)`

Ahora en que momento deseas activarlo, depende de ti.

Answer (score 0):

Para desactivar el botón, como te dicen por arriba:

```
timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         boton.setEnable(false) // con esto no podroas pulsarlo hasta que lo actives
        }
```

A parte, si quieres hacerlo invisible, debajo de boton.setEnabl... pones

```
boton.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Esto es similar o igual a la respuesta de @AshleyG, incluso la misma falta de ortografía :-D **¿Cual es la diferencia con la otra respuesta?**

Comment: Obvio, está copypasteado, añadiendo cómo ponerlo invisible.

Comment: @Jorgesys como que falta de ortografía eh jaja

Comment: @PabloGonzález esta conducta es muy mal vista dentro del sitio ...

Comment: Pone bien claramente: "COMO TE DICEN POR ARRIBA:"

Y luego yo personalmente añado cómo hacerlo invisible. Veis fantasmas donde no los hay...